# Laravel ошибка Route

Tags: php

Содержание роута:

```
Route::get('category/{category}', 'Product_Controller@index');
```

Содержание контроллера:

```
$data = Category::where('alias', $category)
            ->firstOrfail();
```

Запись в базе данных:

```
поле alias = 'category/subcategory'

При переходе на страницу site.com/category/subcategory выдает ошибку: 
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Смотри и читай последний пост, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388326/add-sub-category-laravel-5-2

Comment: Принял решение хранить SLUG url в базе данных, записи имеют вид category/subcategory, и если с просмотром страниц вида site.com/category проблем нет, то с просмотром страниц вида site.com/category/subcategory возникают проблемы выдается ошибка (1/1) NotFoundHttpException

Comment: Обновил вопрос )